# How to concat various Symbian descriptors

Tags: mobile, symbian, descriptor

I am having some difficulty working with Symbian descriptors. I would essentially like to take various descriptors and concat them together into one larger descriptor, perhaps placing them into an RBuf. Also the pieces of data will change in length each type the program runs, below is a bit of skeleton code I have been playing around with but have not been able to build.

```
HBufC8 * aVar = someObj.aVarData();
HBufC * anotherVar = someObj.anotherVarData();
HBuf8 * someVar = someObj.someVarData();

//Perform some operation to convert the descriptors to the same type and add them to a RBuf;

RBuf toLog;
toLog.CreateL( _L("Info to Log"));
toLog.Append( aVar );
toLog.Append( anotherVar );
toLog.Append( someVar );
```

I have not been able to correclty figure out how to convert and add the descriptors to the buffer, as you can see from the comment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append() takes a reference to TDesC, as a param. So, your code should be like below:

```
toLog.Append( *aVar );
toLog.Append( *anotherVar );
toLog.Append( *someVar );
```

Comment: Quick question, why do you use *aVar instead of aVar->Des() ?

Comment: de-referencing hbufc descriptors (only) to get the embedded buf is faster than using the full-function-call aVar->Des(). this is the basic rule of thumb for hbufc descriptors in symbian (and we followed it judiciously within symbian organization).

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks approximately correct. What error do you get?
Beware you are mixing 8 and 16-bit descriptor types.

Read http://descriptors.blogspot.com/